# Using string translation in adapter return numbers

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to use translation string in my adapter but it returns numbers instead

```
if(currentItem.budget != null){
  holder.budget.text = "$ " + currentItem.budget.format()
} else {
  holder.budget.text = R.string.open_to_suggestions.toString()
}
```

`R.string.open_to_suggestions.toString()` supposed to return string text `Open to suggestions` but it returns numbers such as `2131755113` not sure why! **any idea?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the string resource you must use `context.getString()`

```
if(currentItem.budget != null) {
  holder.budget.text = "$ " + currentItem.budget.format()
} else { 
  val context = holder.itemView.context
  holder.budget.text = context.getString(R.string.open_to_suggestions)
}
```

Please take a look at the definition of getString [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getString(int,%20java.lang.Object...))